# Unsigned char plaguing my code

Tags: c, kernel

In the [C library](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:memcpy#Implementation) an implementation of `memcpy` might look like this:

```
#include <stddef.h> /* size_t */
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char *dp = dest;
    const char *sp = src;
    while (n--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;
    return dest;
}
```

Nice, clean and type agnostic right? But when following a kernel tutorial, the prototypes look like this:

```
unsigned char *memcpy(unsigned char *dest, const unsigned char *src, int count);
```

I've attempted to implement it like this:

```
{
    unsigned char *dp = dest;
    unsigned const char *sp = src;
    while (count--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;

    return dest;
}
```

But I'm quite wary of seeing `unsigned char` everywhere and potentially nasty bugs resulting from casts.

1. Should I attempt to use `uint8_t` and other variants wherever possible instead of `unsigned TYPE`?
2. Sometimes I see `unsigned char *` instead of `const char*`. Should this be considered a bug?

Answer (score 0):

What have you seen at C library implementation of `memcpy` that is to confirm C programming standard ie that is how C programming standard defined the `memcpy` interface. And what have you seen at kernel tutorial is totally depends on the tutorial writer, how he designed his kernel and code. AFAIU, to show how to write a kernel and how internal components needs to be glued and built, you can avoid thinking too much about whether to use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` (these kind of decision needs to be made based on whether you really want your kernel to expand at certain level) they are same, but helps readability of your project.

And, regarding the second point - if you really confident that you should use `const char *` instead of `unsigned char *` then yes fix it. But, also concentrate on how kernel works, how memory/video/peripheral devices are setup initialized etc.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as far as C99 is concerned, (u)int8_t must be available if the underlying machine has a primitive 8-bit integer (with no padding)... and not otherwise.  For C99 the basic unit of memory is the char, which technically may have any number of bits.  So, from that perspective, unsigned char is more correct than uint8_t.  POSIX, on the other hand, has decided that the 8-bit byte has achieved tablet-of-stone status, so CHARBIT == 8, forever, and the difference between (u)int8_t and (unsigned/signed) char is academic.

The ghastly legacy of the ambiguous signed-ness of char, we just get to live with.

I like to `typedef unsigned char byte` pretty early, and have done with.

I note that `memcmp()` is defined to compare on the basis of unsigned char.  So I can see some logic in treating all `memxxx()` as taking unsigned char.

I'm not sure I would describe `memcpy(void* dst, ...)` as "type agnostic"... what memcpy is doing is moving *chars*, but by declaring the arguments in this way the programmer is auto-magically relieved of casting to char*.  Anyone who passes an int* and a count of ints, expecting memcpy to do the usual pointer arithmetic magic, is destined for a short, sharp shock !  So, in this case, if you are required to cast to unsigned char*, then I would argue that it is clearer and safer.  (Everybody learns very quickly what `memxxx()` do, so the extra clarity would generally be seen as a pain in the hindquarters.  I agree that casts in general should be treated as "taking off the seat belt and pressing the pedal to the metal", but not so much in this case.)

Clearly `unsigned char*` and `const char*` are quite different to each other (how different would depend on the signed-ness of `char`), but whether the appearance of one or the other is a bug or not would depend on the context.